# How do I run PHPUnit in Laravel from my Windows Command prompt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a Laravel app installed in my directory f:\lara_app. I use PHP artisan serve to run the app. I have Laravel version 5.4.36 (via Composer Install)

I am not trying my hand in using the PHP Unit to do testing. Inside f:/lara_app/tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php, I have the following codes:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
         $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function myFirstTest()
    {
        $value = 'Hello World';
        $this->assertTrue( 'Hello' === $value, 'Value should be Hello World');
    }     
}
```

I now try to run the test from my command prompt:

```
f:\lara_app> .vendor/phpunit/phpuni/phpunit
```

But I'm getting the message below:

'.vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

How do I run the PHPUnit test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your answer is in your question. why the `.` before *vendor*?

Comment: The tutorial I'm following has the . before the vendor -  the author is using a Mac though. I thought the shell commands would be the same in both platforms

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
"./vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

Answer (score 25):

This should work on windows

```
f:\lara_app> php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me

```
C:\code\project-name> vendor\bin\phpunit
```

Answer (score 6):

For every Laravel project from version 7.x, if you want to run tests you can do one of these:

- **You can use artisan:** `php artisan test` [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/testing#artisan-test-runner)
- **Or you can use phpunit:** if you want to run phpunit on windows, only by typing `phpunit`, you can create a bat file in your project's main directory by running this command:`@echo php vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit > phpunit.bat` and then you can type `phpunit` in your command and enjoy.

Happy Testing...

Comment: `php artisan test` do the work perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Also for future readers, you can run it on windows powershell, without having to change anything, if you're in the root directory of your project. Simply Type

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes or use backslashes.  Unlike linux, Windows does not like forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have phpunit in `composer.json`, and run:

```
composer update
```

And then run PHPUnit:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```